# Why the kibana shows mutiple node?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana

In my project, I need to collect logs from my apps. So, I decide to use slasticsearch and kibana. The following docker file is used to deploy the elasticsearch and kibana on my docker swarm. Then, I can access the kibana in my browser.

```
   version: "3.8"
    services:
      elasticsearch:
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.9.2
        ports:
          - target: 9200
            published: 9200
            protocol: tcp
            mode: host
          - target: 9300
            published: 9300
            protocol: tcp
            mode: host
        ulimits:
          nproc: 65535
          nofile:
            soft: 65535
            hard: 65535
          memlock:
            soft: -1
            hard: -1
        volumes:
          - elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        environment:
          # ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx1g -Xms1g"
          ELASTIC_PASSWORD: te
          xpack.license.self_generated.type: basic
          xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: "false"
          xpack.security.enabled: "false"
          xpack.monitoring.collection.enabled: "true"
          cluster.name: "docker-cluster"
          network.host: 0.0.0.0
          bootstrap.memory_lock: 'true'
          node.name: elk_elasticsearch.{{.Task.Slot}}
          discovery.type: ""
          discovery.seed_hosts: tasks.elasticsearch
          cluster.initial_master_nodes: elk_elasticsearch.1,elk_elasticsearch.2,elk_elasticsearch.3
          network.publish_host: _eth0_
        networks:
          - elk
        deploy:
          replicas: 3
          placement:
            max_replicas_per_node: 1
          restart_policy:
            condition: any
      kibana:
        image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.9.2
        ports:
          - "6017:5601"
        networks:
          - elk
        environment:
          server.name: kibana
          server.host: 0.0.0.0
          elasticsearch.hosts: "http://elasticsearch:9200"
          monitoring.ui.container.elasticsearch.enabled: "true"
          elasticsearch.username: elastic
          elasticsearch.password: te
        deploy:
          mode: replicated
          replicas: 1
    volumes:
      elasticsearch:
        driver: local    
    networks:
      elk:
        driver: overlay
```

The kibana does not require me to enter the username and password. Is this normal? Am I missing something?

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is an expected behaviour because you are disabling the security features. You need to change `xpack.security.enabled: "false"` to `xpack.security.enabled: "true"` in order for your Elastic Stack to use the security features.

Comment: Thanks! I am following this https://codingfundas.com/setting-up-elasticsearch-6-8-with-kibana-and-x-pack-security-enabled/index.html

Comment: @Erika if my comment helped, please mark it as the solution :)